# Using prototype replace one character with another in c

Tags: c, string, pointers, character

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
void repl(char *string, char oldc, char newc);

char text[60] = { "I am going to replace the character a with the character i";
char newc = 'b';
char oldc = 'a';

int main()
{
    void repl(char *string, char oldc, char newc);

    return 0;

}

void repl(char *string, char oldc, char newc)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < *string; i++)
    {
        if (*(string + i) == oldc)
        {
            *(string + i) == newc;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

I am trying to replace the character `a` with the character `b`. 
I know how to do this without using pointers but I am not too sure when it comes to pointers.
The prototype I was given was:

```
void repl(char *string, char oldc, char newc);
```

Comment: For any valid pointer like `string` and index like `i`, the expressions `string[i]` and `*(string + i)` are equal.

Comment: Your question is? You don't even call the function.

Comment: Also, you're doing something very unusual. Many beginners by mistake use assignment `=` instead of comparison `==`. You do the opposite. A good compiler should be able to warn you about it, and if not then enable more warnings.

Comment: Lastly, take a closer look at the loop condition... It is far from correct, and the loop will (with the string you probably want to use) iterate 73 times.

Comment: You have an uh...dangling...curly brace in the line `char text[60] = { "I am going to replace the character a with the character i";`. That doesn't need to be there and will cause compilation issues.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you're after. I seriously recommend reading up on some basic C programming topics, such as calling functions and declaring char arrays. In the meantime...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
void repl(char *string, char oldc, char newc);

char text[60] = "I am going to replace the character a with the character i";
char newc = 'i';
char oldc = 'a';

int main()
{
    repl(text, oldc, newc);
    return 0;
}

void repl(char *string, char oldc, char newc)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i]; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == oldc)
        {
            string[i] = newc;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", string);
}
```